# Confirm a form & display message if form is valid with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm developing my Django application and I would like to use JavaScript in order to improve my website.

I have a form and I would like to display 2 things :

- Confirm the form before submit
- If form is well submitted, display a message : 'Form is saved'

It's the first time I'm using JS and I need help to make this process.

This is my code :

```
    <form class = "form" method='POST' action=''> {% csrf_token %}
        <br></br>
        {{ form.as_p}}
        <br></br>

        <button type="submit">Valider</button>
    </form>

    <script>
        $('#form').submit(function() {
        var c = confirm("Click OK to continue?");
        return c; //you can just return c because it will be true or false
    });
    </script>
```

And if my form is valid and saved :

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
                $(document).on('Valider', 'form.form', function(form) {
                var $form = $(form);
                $.ajax({
                    url:"/path_to_my_html_file/BC_form2.html",
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function(form) {
                    alert("Form is saved");
                    }
                });
                });
            </script>
```

Could you help me ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can try to adopt by your purpose this code:

```js
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
    // Prevents form to be submitted by default post request with page reloading
    e.preventDefault();
    if (confirm("Click OK to continue?")) {
      // Here you can call your AJAX request
      callAjax($('input[type=text]').val())
    }
});

function callAjax(value) {
  // Making AJAX request to your endpoint
  // GET ipify just for example
  $.ajax({
      url:"https://api.ipify.org?format=json",
      type: "GET",
      success: function(form) {
        alert("Form is saved");
      }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <form id="form"> 
    <input type="hidden" value="MOCK FOR CSRF TOKEN" />
    <br></br>
    <input type="text" required />
    <br></br>

    <button type="submit">Valider</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I get several problems. First one, doesn't take account if my form is valid (all fields well filled) or not. Then, if my form is valid, I have both windows but form `submit` button doesn't work ^^

Comment: @Valentin if you use `required` attribute and not all inputs filled - form submit not firing. Also, if you want to add additional validation, you can make your verification inside onSubmit handler and before confirmation. So, if your form is invalid you just show an error to the user and stops function execution with return, for example.

Comment: Ok I have to understand your answer and see how I can do that ;) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use .valid() in submit function

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
  var isValid=$("#form").valid();
           if (isValid) { //If there is no validation error

            var c = confirm("Click OK to continue?");
            if(c){
              $.ajax({
                url:"/path_to_my_html_file/BC_form2.html",
                type: "POST",
                success: function(form) {
                  alert("Form is saved");
                }
              });

            }

          } 
          else {
            alert('form is not valid');                               
          }

        });
</script>
```

Comment: I have to see why I don't have any alerts which is displayed ^^